# jquery menu bar fadein fadeout error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so after some questioning i wrote a jsfiddle page to show you what im tried. When going over the link the div shows up but when the mouse goes over it it fadesout and again fadesin. Isnt posible that when going above the div it just stays there until you move the mouse away?

the example on jsfiddle works when you go above the menubar Crepes..
here´s my jquery code.. the css and html are on jsfiddle

thanks for the help!

http://jsfiddle.net/DFxB7/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#crep, #front").hover(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#front").fadeIn();   

         }, 

            function(){
            $("#front").fadeOut();
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Try using `.mouseover` and `.mouseout` instead of `.hover`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the event `.stop()` like this:

```
    $("#crep, #front").hover(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#front").stop().fadeIn();   

         }, 
         function(){
            $("#front").stop().fadeOut();
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DFxB7/2/)

Comment: thank you very very much! that helped :)  could you explain me why stop() helped and what does in this situation before fadein?

Comment: stop() function help in this case because it stopped the other event and recognize if you are on hover or not @user3013745

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may give you the functionality you're after...

```
var toggle = 0;
$("#crep, #front").hover(function (e) {         
    if(toggle == 0)
    {
        toggle = 1;
        $("#front").stop().fadeIn();   
    }else{
        toggle = 0;
        $("#front").stop().fadeOut();   
    }
});
```